# Ionic Android Build on Mac

Tags: android, macos, ionic-framework, build

I'm trying to build my android app, and for the past 5 days getting one error:

```
Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
```

I've already tried all sorts of way to fix this and NOTHING works. I'm about to give up, as I really don't know what to do anymore. Any advice or recommendations from people who might have faced similar problems will be highly appreciated!!!!

Here is the reason why:

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed 
Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
Gradle: not installed 
Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
Looked here: /usr/local/Caskroom/android-sdk/25.2.3/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper

Requirements check results for ios:
Apple OS X: installed darwin
Xcode: installed 8.3.2
ios-deploy: installed 1.9.0
CocoaPods: installed 
Error: Some of requirements check failed
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what issues you're having, but I guess I'll answer with some information that I've found/Info I need from you:

Have you gone through https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/ for the Android section (installed Android Studio, Java JDK, etc). Just asking to make sure.

Also is this on an existing project or a brand new one? If you have the chance, you should give it a shot with one of their empty app templates. Sometimes this can help you narrow it down to a workflow challenge, because in my experience the larger your project, the harder it is to find the issue.